# Can I stop event propagation on certain function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have some DIVs, and other developer bind them a click event name `fn_propagation`.

And now I want to add a new function to them name `fn_stoppropagation`.

The problem is when I call `e.stopPropagation()` in `fn_stoppropagation`, it will stop event propagation in `fn_propagation` too.

How can I keep event propagation in `fn_propagation` but stop propagation in my added function? ( I know add event to each DIV by ID and stop use stopPropagation() can do this, but i don't think it's a good way. )

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/android/3GurB/2/

HTML:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <div id='div2'>
        <div id='div3'>
            Click Me
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div').click(fn_propagation)      // Other developer add this event
        .click(fn_stoppropagation); // What I going to add.

// I want to keep propagation of this function 
function fn_propagation(){
    alert('propagation '+$(this).attr('id')+' called');
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
}

// But stop propagation of this function
function fn_stoppropagation(e){
    alert('stoppropagation '+$(this).attr('id')+' called');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

When `Click Me` is clicked, expect output:

```
   propagation div3 called     // called
   stoppropagation div3 called // called
   propagation div2 called     // expected, but NOT called, 
   propagation div1 called     // expected, but NOT called,
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/U3kn3/ ?

Comment: This is doing exactly what I would expect.  Why do you think it is wrong (apart from me being wrong)

Comment: poor example using `'div'` as selector...surely the selectors are more specific than that?

Comment: The function doesn't bubble, the event does. Stopping the event from any handler stops it. It can't both bubble and not bubble at the same time.

Comment: @charlietfl: I think OP did that as a simple way of assigning handlers to all the nested elements for illustration.

Comment: Well, what is it actually you want to do? May be we could help with that because as far as I know, stopPropagation means it is going to stop click from bubbling to its parent divs.

Comment: What I mean is, why would you try and use stopPropagate() when you don't want it to stop bubbling

Comment: For some reason I must keep this `'div'` as selector. @Christophe resolve my problem and NOT just complain or vote-me-down how wrong the example is!

Comment: @Lokesh Suthar: Thank you, I known what stopPropagation means now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propagation happens in the DOM, it can only be on or off for the whole element, not for a specific event handler.

My suggestion: compare the current element with the [click target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
function fn_stoppropagation(e){
  if (this===e.target) {
    // the following will only run for the target, not its ancestors
    alert('stoppropagation '+$(this).attr('id')+' called');
  }
}
```

Comment: @andyf: Are you sure you deepest element with the handler will never have another nested element? Like adding a nested `<span>` in your example? If it does, this won't work.

Comment: @Blue Skies: It's a problem... Maybe I can use $('div *') to make it work?

Comment: @BlueSkies good point. In this case, maybe use $(e.target).closest("div")[0] instead?

Comment: @andyf: You'll be assigning the handler to all elements that inherit from all divs. It'll probably work as long as you ultimately don't care what element was clicked.

Comment: @Christophe: That seems like a possibility.

Comment: @Christophe: Thanks for your idea. It works like a charm! http://jsfiddle.net/android/3GurB/8/

Comment: @Blue Skies: It's a good idea by Christophe: http://jsfiddle.net/android/3GurB/8/

Comment: @andyf another idea that might work for you: only attach fn_stoppropagation to the outer div, and within the function access $(e.target).closest("div")[0]

Comment: @Christophe Less event binding on page. I'll try it. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is nested divs, each handling click. Since they are nested, the event bubbles up - starting with innermost div. So you cannot `stopPropogation` and expect it to propagate up the bubble. `stopPropogation` is meant exactly for that - stop bubbling up the event to other handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, because event propagation is independent of event handlers, so you can't stop the event for some and don't stop for others.

You may think it makes sense to be able to stop it only for some, but that's because your case is a special one: the target and its ancestors have the same handler.

But in a more general case, a bubbling event triggers event handlers which can be different for each element, so stopping the event propagation only for some handlers has no meaning.

Then, the correct approach is modifying the event handlers instead of the event.
For example:

```
var stopped = false;
function fn_stoppropagation(e){
    if(stopped !== (stopped=true)){
        /* Code here */
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3GurB/5/)

Comment: Seems like a good solution to me. Probably needs a way to reset though.

Comment: How does this help? Since fn_stoppropagation is never called more than once anyway.

Comment: Can you provide your Demo?

Comment: @VikramRao: Sure it is... when it bubbles up to the next element with the same handler assigned.

Comment: @andyf Sorry I forgot to add the link

Comment: @Oriol: Thanks for your DEMO, but it call `fn_stoppropagation` only once. I think @Christophe is a better way.